# How do I install/use Extjs extensions and plugins

Tags: plugins, extjs

Sorry for the newbie question, but how do I install or go about using an Extjs Extension or plugin I found through the extjs forums?

Comment: Don't want to sound flippant, but would that not be better asked there?

Comment: I hope I don't sound flippant either, but I think Stackoverflow is a better place to get an answer than a technology-specific forum.  There's just more people here.  Frankly, I don't know why any company would use their own forum anymore.  Google doesn't even do that, and if anyone has an online community of developers, it's them.

Answer (score 7):

Just include the file and start using it - you don't need to register anything with ExtJS. :)

Answer (score 7):

To clarify, include the file(s) **after** you have included the required Ext files.  Plugins and extensions plug into or override existing code, so if the code being plugged into is not there it won't work.  But yes, simply including the plugin/extension is the only requirement.

If you have problems with specific plugins or extensions, you'll want to ask directly on the Ext forums.